# Using web services to connect to database at retrieve a list of Symptoms

Tags: web-services

I'm simply trying to read all symptoms from a database and store them in a list for a web service client to use. Symptoms contain: symptomID (int) and symptomName (string).

How do I return a list of symptoms to the web service client containing the symptom id and name.

The code below is taken although I can't seem to define symptom in the web service.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "MyWebService")
public class MyWebService {

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "getAllSym")
public String getAllSym() {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:


Connection con;
Statement ps;
ResultSet rs;    
List allSymptoms = new ArrayList(); 

int i = 0;
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    ps = con.createStatement();
    rs = ps.executeQuery("select * from symptoms");
    while (rs.next()) {
        allSymptoms.add(new Symptom(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
        i++;
        }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error Data : " + e.getMessage());
}

return allSymptoms;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Java expert, but why not change the return type of your method to be `List`?

Comment: Your method is `public String getAllSym()`. Make that `public List getAllSym()`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Java and want return the object in json format I'll recommend Gson API, a Json parser made by google. It will looks like this:

```
return new Gson().toJson(allSymptoms);
```

Comment: I'd rather not use a JSON parser but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood what the JSON parser provided.
Am I correct in thinking that the code I've written would be correct and JSON allows me to pass the Symptom back to the client?

Comment: Yes! the allSymptons is your arraylist, an object in Java, but when you work with webservices you need to expose this object in a more commom format, you have to choose between JSON, XML or other format.